# Missing file for Javascript debugging in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Whenever I open a PDF in IE with javascript debugging enabled I get the following error message:

"The file debugger.js is missing from the Javascripts folder. The Debugger will not run correctly without this file."

I recently installed Adobe Acrobat 9. Where can I find this debugger.js file? It's nowhere to be found on my hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Download `debugger.js` here:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/debugger.js

(You can find this link and other resources on this page:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/pdf/topic_js.html)

Then follow the instructions given under "Using the Debugger with Adobe Reader" starting on page 28 of the [JavaScript Developer Guide](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_developer_guide.pdf) to make use of the downloaded file.